# Can we train Spacy for text summarization

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3

Spacy can train for NER, text classification. And we can use it for summarization with its functionalities, so that
Can we train spacy in order to improve its accuracy in summarization?

Answer (score 1):

NLP distinguishes two types of text summarization: abstractive and extractive.

**Abstractive summarization** generates novel short text based on long textual input. The state of the art are variants of neural sequence-to-sequence models. Spacy *does not* implement these models, also this requires quite large training data and computation resources.

**Extractive summarization** extracts the most informative parts from a long text. There are various approaches spanning from simple statistical methods to complex neural models. One approach easily doable using Spacy is [finding probable keywords in the text and then extracting sentences with the most keywords present](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/text-summarization-using-spacy-ca4867c6b744). If you have training data, an alternative would tagging spans in the text, which is also doable in Spacy, similarly to named entity recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Methodology for text summarization:

1. Text cleaning entails the removal of stop words, punctuation marks, and the conversion of words to lower case.
2. Workplace Tokenization: Tokenize each word in phrases.
3. Word Frequency Table: To compute the normalized word frequency count, count each word's frequency and divide the maximum frequency by the frequency of each word.
4. Sentence Tokenization: The sentence is tokenized based on how frequently it is used.
5. Recapitulation

   ```
   pip install spacy
   import spacy
   from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS

   stopwords=list(STOP_WORDS)
   from string import punctuation
   punctuation=punctuation+ '\n'

   text="The text you want to summarize goes here.A long para is preferred."

   nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
   doc= nlp(text)
   tokens=[token.text for token in doc]
   ```

Now calculate the word frequencies:

```
   word_frequencies={}
   for word in doc:
       if word.text.lower() not in stopwords:
          if word.text.lower() not in punctuation:
             if word.text not in word_frequencies.keys():
                 word_frequencies[word.text] = 1
             else:
                 word_frequencies[word.text] += 1
```

Take the highest frequency and divide it by the total number of frequencies to get normalized word frequencies.

```
    max_frequency=max(word_frequencies.values())
    for word in word_frequencies.keys():
    word_frequencies[word]=word_frequencies[word]/max_frequency

    #get sentence tokens
    sentence_tokens= [sent for sent in doc.sents]
```

By summing the word frequencies in each sentence, we can now compute the most essential phrases.

```
    sentence_scores = {}
    for sent in sentence_tokens:
        for word in sent:
            if word.text.lower() in word_frequencies.keys():
               if sent not in sentence_scores.keys():                            
                  sentence_scores[sent]=word_frequencies[word.text.lower()]
               else:
                  sentence_scores[sent]+=word_frequencies[word.text.lower()]
```

Import nlargest from headhq and compute 30% of text with the highest score.

```
    from heapq import nlargest
    select_length=int(len(sentence_tokens)*0.3)
    select_length
    summary=nlargest(select_length, sentence_scores,key=sentence_scores.get
```

Summary

```
    final_summary=[word.text for word in summary]
    final_summary
    summary=''.join(final_summary)
    summary
```